# How to limit number of characters in Swift, UITextField if I am using my own designed keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I actually tried with the help of the this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let textFieldText = textField.text,
        let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textFieldText) else {
            return false
    }
    let substringToReplace = textFieldText[rangeOfTextToReplace]
    let count = textFieldText.count - substringToReplace.count + string.count
    return count <= 10
}
```

But it works only if I am typing on my computer. But if I am typing with the keyboard which I designed it doesn't work. By the way my designed keyboard as follows.

```
@IBAction func digits(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
      textField.text! += String(sender.tag)
        
  }
```

Is there any function to limit number of characters to this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Use UITextField extension to fix the number of character of a textField as following:-

```
private var kAssociationKeyMaxLength: Int = 0

extension UITextField {

@IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
    get {
        if let length = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyMaxLength) as? Int {
            return length
        } else {
            return Int.max
        }
    }
    set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyMaxLength, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMaxLength), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

func isInputMethod() -> Bool {
    if let positionRange = self.markedTextRange {
        if let _ = self.position(from: positionRange.start, offset: 0) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}


@objc func checkMaxLength(textField: UITextField) {
    
    guard !self.isInputMethod(), let prospectiveText = self.text,
        prospectiveText.count > maxLength
        else {
            return
    }
    
    let selection = selectedTextRange
    let maxCharIndex = prospectiveText.index(prospectiveText.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
    text = prospectiveText.substring(to: maxCharIndex)
    selectedTextRange = selection
  }

}
```

Usage in your code like:-

```
self.textField.maxLength = 8
```

Also, you can fix it from storyboard by selecting your text field, check-in attributes inspector as shown in the following image:-

[image]

Comment: It didn't worked as anothers bruh. It works only if I adding popup keyboard or writing by my computer to my textField. But to my designed keyboard it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
 guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
 let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length
 return newLength <= 10}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.